# I run dconf reset -f / and lost all new gnome features for ubuntu 2022.10

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome

I run the dconf reset -f / and i have lost all the new look and features that come with ubuntu 2022.10. any idea how I revert them, for example:
The top bar reverted to the old style, the dock reverted to the old basic one. And also the settings on the setting app went back to the older ubuntu setting

Comment: Hm, Is something in your cache maybe?   `ls -al .cache/dconf/`